WooCommerce Subscriptions custom shortcode for recurring totals
I need a shortcode to display the monthly recurring totals for a WooCommerce subscription order. After checkout, I'm requiring a customer to sign a lease for the rental order they just placed and need a way to show what their first monthly payment will be. Because I prorate, the order subtotals and totals don't contain the correct info.
I tried using the following, based on the documentation here: https://woocommerce.com/document/subscriptions/develop/functions/
add_shortcode('wdm_recurring_totals', 'wmd_my_custom_function');
function wmd_my_custom_function(){
    WC_Subscription::get_total();
}

It seems to just throw an error on testing (I'm inexperienced with PHP).

Your question is unclear: Where and how are you trying to use a shortcode that display  the subscription recurring totals?

You can achieve this by creating a custom shortcode that calculates the monthly recurring total for a WooCommerce subscription. Here’s how you can do it:
add_shortcode('wdm_recurring_totals', 'wmd_my_custom_function');
function wmd_my_custom_function() {
// Check if the user is logged in
if ( ! is_user_logged_in() ) {
    return 'You need to be logged in to view this information.';
}

// Get the current user's subscriptions
$user_id = get_current_user_id();
$subscriptions = wcs_get_users_subscriptions( $user_id );

// Initialize total
$total = 0;

// Loop through each subscription
foreach ( $subscriptions as $subscription ) {
    // Check if the subscription is active
    if ( $subscription->get_status() == 'active' ) {
        // Get the monthly recurring total
        $total += $subscription->get_total();
    }
}

// Check if total is zero
if ( $total === 0 ) {
    return 'You have no active subscriptions.';
}

// Return the formatted total
return 'Your first monthly payment will be: ' . wc_price( $total );

}
